# iPhone takes ~3 seconds to switch music tracks

Tags: ios, iphone

I have 600 songs in my iPhone's music library, with some of them being more than an hour long.
Lately (since iOS 7.1 upgrade) the songs have been taking around 3 or more seconds to change to the next/previous song, when changed from the lock screen or control centre.

If I do it from the music app, there is no such delay.

Why is this happening?
It never happened on pre-iOS 7.1- is there anything that I can do about this? I've already tried restoring the device to iOS 6.1.3 (via saved hashes), and the delay is gone.

Is this a bug in iOS 7.1+?

The device is an iPhone 4, and I have no desire to upgrade to a newer iPhone, since what I would gain would be very little.

Comment: what iphone are you talking about? iPhone 4?

Comment: @Gotschi Yes- updated the question.

Comment: Do you use iTunes match ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler No, I don't.